# ggpairs change axis label font size

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, ggpairs

I have a dataset with relatively large column names. When displaying the ggpairs, they fall outside of the limit, and one cannot read the each plot labels. I have tried `theme(axis.text = element_text(size=8))` inside the `ggpairs()` command, but it doesn't work. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `theme` and check if you size is high enough like this:

```r
library(GGally)
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1], 1000), ]

pm <- ggpairs(
  diamonds.samp[, 1:5],
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = cut),
  upper = list(continuous = wrap("density", alpha = 0.5), combo = "box_no_facet"),
  lower = list(continuous = wrap("points", alpha = 0.3), combo = wrap("dot_no_facet", alpha = 0.4)),
  title = "Diamonds"
)
pm
```

[image]

```r
pm + theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't change the axis labels, it changes the axis text. I think these labels are from `facet_wrap()`, so it's for that one has to change the font size somehow.

Answer (score 2):

To change the column and row labels in the grey boxes of facet_wrap() and ggpairs(), you can specify the size of the **strip.text** as follows:

```
pm + theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 5),
           strip.text.y = element_text(size = 5))
```

Is this what you meant?